# A link with swift webview application target _blank is not working

Tags: swift

I'm a beginner, sorry I did webview with swift, but a link with target _blank doesn't work

Comment: You'd need to specify a valid url to the request parameter. _blank is not a page on the server. Anyways, why do you need something like that to work?

Comment: I'm doing a webwiev application with swift target blank links don't work

Comment: Web view is for accessing pages from the server. It's not like Google Chrome where you can type about:blank and the page is served from local. Do you need a working example of WKWebView. I guess that's the one you are using.

Comment: yes working example of WKWebView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a UIViewRepresentable class for the WKWebView from UIKit. The UIViewRepresentable class can be used to create and manage views(UIView) from UIKit in SwiftUI. There are two views in the project,

1. ContentView lists the urls from string array. Selecting an url navigates to the Detail view.
2. The Detail view shows the web page for the selected url using WKWebView.

Hope this helps. Here's the code.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var urls: [String] = ["https://www.stackoverflow.com", "https://www.yahoo.com"]
    @State private var hideStatusBar = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(urls, id: \.self) { url in
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(url: url)) {
                            Text(url)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Main")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var url: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Webview(url: url)
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}

struct Webview: UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: String
    typealias UIViewType = WKWebView

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Webview>) -> WKWebView {
        let wkWebView = WKWebView()
        guard let url = URL(string: self.url) else {
            return wkWebView
        }

        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        wkWebView.load(request)
        return wkWebView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Webview>) {
    }
}
```